# center sweetalert input textbox

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I'm trying to center an input textbox using sweet alert.

Do you have any idea how to do this?
Attached are the screenshot and the code.
Thanks!!

```js
swal({
            title: "Title",
            text: "text",
            type: "input",
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            inputPlaceholder: "mm:ss"
        },
        function (inputValue) {
            swal("Nice!", "You wrote: " + inputValue, "success");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Screenshot of what I get:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcZCj.png)

Comment: by default, the width of an input is 100%. perhaps you have applied a custom width in the css. in the same way, where you have applied the width, add the centering rule as well

Comment: The one in the snippet here appears centered for me (in Chrome).

Comment: The input box appears centered to me. Are you try trying to center the text within the input box?